# List of Figures and Tables won't get translated in the Table of Contents using Babel

Tags: babel

Possibly a newbie question but here we go:

I'm using Babel to translate titles automatically in my project. When focusing on my Table of Contents I realized that the texts for the List of Tables, List of Figures and the Table of Contents itself aren't being translated, but when I go to each individual section they are!

These are the packages I'm using. Most of them came with the template I'm using:

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
```

I added my table of contents and lists in this order

```
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

I also been using the `\addto` command to try to rename the command using Babel, but it doesn't work either.

```
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Lista de Tablas}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please complete your given code snippet to an compilable complete minimal example showing which document class you use.

Comment: My mistake. There was a .cls file for the template overriding those texts.
Lesson learned.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is actually unrelated to TeX - LaTeX (a file that cause the problem).